# How can I create a randomHop function that would return certain coordinates?

Tags: function-construction, conditional, homework

I've tried to create a function that's equal to a loop containing 4 if functions, one for each integer, but the result would not show the desired outcome. How can I go about doing this question?
Write a Mathematica function called randomHop that takes as its argument a list containing two coordinates x and y; your definition should begin

randomHop[{x_, y_}] :=

The function should then generate a random integer equal to 1,  2, 3 or 4, and then

- if r is equal to 1, return {x, y}/3;
- if r is 2, return {x, y}/3 + {2/3, 0};
- if r is 3, return RotationMatrix[[Pi]/3].{x, y}/3 + {1/3, 0};
- if r is 4, return RotationMatrix[-[Pi]/3].{x, y}/3 + {1/2, Sqrt[3]/6};

Comment: see  [RandomInteger](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RandomInteger.html) and [Switch](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Switch.html) in the docs

Comment: If you you’re required to use `RandomInteger`, then I guess you have to. But it’s a bit inefficient. I would just used `randomHop[{x_, y_}] := RandomChoice[{choices}]`.

Answer (score 4):

Maybe like this?

```
randomfun[r_][{x_, y_}] := 
 Piecewise[{
{{x, y}/2, r == 1},
 {{x, y}/3 + {2/3, 0},    r == 2}, 
{RotationMatrix[Pi/3] . {x, y}/3 + {1/3, 0}, r == 3},
 {RotationMatrix[-Pi/3] . {x, y}/3 + {1/2, Sqrt[3]/6}, r == 4}}]
randomfun[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]][{x, y}]
randomfun[#][{x, y}] & /@ RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4}, 2]
NestList[randomfun[RandomInteger[{1, 4}]], {0, 0}, 10]
```

Or as mention in comment,

```
randomHop[{x_, y_}] := 
  RandomChoice[{{x, y}/2, {x, y}/3 + {2/3, 0}, 
    RotationMatrix[Pi/3] . {x, y}/3 + {1/3, 0}, 
    RotationMatrix[-Pi/3] . {x, y}/3 + {1/2, Sqrt[3]/6}}];
NestList[randomHop, {0, 0}, 10]
```

Comment: I've tried using this method, but when i try to put it in a nestlist, I cant seem to get a set of coordinates. I use NestList[randomfun,{0,0},10], but it just gives me an output of 11 "coordinates" that just say randomfun[{0,0}], and so on. Do you think it's something to do with the code that's setting up the randomfun function or something to do with the NestList?

Comment: @jbl Have updated.